# Can I test that a transaction has been added to the database with Selenium IDE?

Tags: mysql, selenium, testing, selenium-ide, acceptance-testing

I am testing using Selenium IDE and Firefox.

Can I check that a transaction done in my website is added to my database without manually opening a new tab with localhost/phpmyadmin and selecting the transaction table?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and shouldn't, directly look in the database with Selenium IDE. You can, and should, indirectly test that the transaction happened.

When you use Selenium, or any other browser controlling or simulating testing tool, you're testing your app from the user's point of view (writing a 'functional' or 'acceptance' test). Users don't know what's in the database -- they just know what they see on the screen. So if doing something in your web app changes something on some page of your web app that a user can see (not phpmyadmin but your application that you're testing), go there in Selenium and test that.

This is the right thing to do even if your testing tool does have a way to look in the database.

If your app writes some kind of information to the database that is never shown to any user, such as auditing information, the only way to test that with Selenium IDE is to add a page (appropriately authenticated!) to your web app so that Selenium IDE can see it. If you aren't able to do that, you need a testing tool that can look in the database.

RSpec and Cucumber, with the Capybara Ruby gem, are examples of testing tools that can both test an application through its user interface and also look in (and even change) the database.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can use it but most people will advise you against it. Here's why :-

1. It can be unreliable. I mean it can lead to many false negative creating a lot of noise in your test result.
2. Very tightly coupled.
3. You will have to run it from Firefox all the time (last time I checked) and you will need Firefox wherever you want to test. [Restriction]
4. Can't use programming tricks like looping, conditions, etc.
5. Difficult to maintain as won't fit in any framework. (or can it?)
6. ...and some more...

I would suggest use Selenium IDE to create a test-case for basic steps you follow. Export it to any language of your liking and then create history. :)

And like Dave said above, you may like to explore other tools specifically for database.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke for "most of the people". Hope they agree.